# LSF -- Giving multiple options for acceptable resource types?

Tags: batch-file, lsf

I'm running some jobs on a cluster that uses the [LSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_LSF) batch scheduling tool. A typical batch request looks like this:

```
bsub -q someQueue -R someResourceType /home/user/myProgram
```

In the cluster that I'm using, there are approximately ten different types of resources. (In other words, ten different types of nodes in the cluster.) There are three resource types that would be acceptable for the batch jobs that I'm running. Therefore, I'd like to make a request that says "use whichever resource type is available out of `resourceType1`, `resourceType2`, or `resourceType3`."

I'm guessing such a request would look something like this:

```
bsub -q someQueue -R {resourceType1 or resourceType2 or resourceType3} /home/user/myProgram
```

Is there a way to do this in LSF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the appropriate syntax:

```
bsub -q someQueue -R "resourceType1|resourceType2|resourceType3" /home/user/myProgram
```

Make sure you don't forget the quotes!